# VBA to insert TOC that can be used by many users

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking to setup a mail merge (Directory merge to use page breaks) template and then have users use a macro to generate a Table of Contents once the file has been created.

I tried recording a macro to go to the first space in the document, add a section break and then insert a TOC and change the numbering so that it does not include the first page, but I see that it uses my username when it loads the building blocks template.

I realise it is messy since it is a recorded and I have found some cleaner code, but then it does not have the header for the TOC.

Is there a way that I can have this work for any user that uses the code?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
 Set myTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("Automatic Table 1").Insert Where:=Selection.Range _
        , RichText:=True
    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```

Tried the following code, but it still uses mypath which has to be the path of the current user. Is the rest of the path the same for each user? Then perhaps I can just somehow extract the username of the current user and insert it into myUsername.

```
Sub ToCAndTitle()
With ActiveDocument
  'Insert a Section break before existing content
  .Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
  .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=.Range(0, 0), RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
     UseHeadingStyles:=True, IncludePageNumbers:=True, UseHyperlinks:=True, _
     HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False
  'Insert a page break before existing content
  .Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
  Application.Templates(mypath).BuildingBlockEntries("BuildingBlockName").Insert Where:=.Range(0, 0), RichText:=True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Has the information provided helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following since "Automatic Table 1" was not available on other users' computers:

```vb
Sub ToCAndTitle()
Dim tmptmplt As Template
With ActiveDocument
  'Insert a Section break before existing content
  .Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
  'Insert a page break before existing content
  .Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
  'Insert Table of contents on first page
  .TablesOfContents.Add _
    Range:=.Range(0, 0)
  'Manually enter text and format as TOC Heading from default template that all users should have
  .Range(0, 0).InsertAfter ("Table of Contents") & vbCr
  .Range(0, 0).Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("TOC Heading")
  'Different first page header to remove number from TOC page
  .Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a template for distribution, store the Building Block in that template rather than in your "private" building blocks template. Then it will be available to anyone using the template.

1. Create the content to be saved as a building block in the template or a document created from the template. Select this content.
2. Insert/Quick Parts/Save selection to Quick Part Gallery
3. Set the name, the gallery and category under which it should be stored, as usual...
4. ... Select the template that will be distributed from **Save in**

Change the code in the question to:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
 Set myTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    myTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Automatic Table 1").Insert _
        Where:=Selection.Range _
        , RichText:=True
   'Note: the macro probably does not need the rest of the lines of code
   'that were generated by the macro recorder - comment them out or delete them 
   If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but the Automatic Table 1 could not be inserted from the other user's computer either.

Comment: @CduToit It's unclear how/where you're saving this TOC as a Building Block entry, but I'm guessing it hasn't been stored in the template you're creating and distributing, or it's been saved with a different name than what is used in the code.

Comment: I do not necessarily want to use it as a Building Block entry, I just want something that will work on anybody's computer. That is why I ended up just adding a TOC and a separate header, since it looks like ActiveDocument.TableOfContents.Add is independent of the template and ActiveDocument.Styles("TOC Heading") seems to work - not sure if this reads from the template though.